# Запретить выборку строк с флагом

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Возмножно ли на уровне конфигурации EF сделать так, чтобы строки с флагом Deleted, например, были невидимы на всех уровнях? 
Например, есть колонка Deleted и чтоб не проверять в каждом методе, отмечена ли она, сделать, чтоб EF просто не видел эту строку.

Comment: что значит "не видел"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/10/soft-delete-pattern-for-entity.html
Статья, в которой описано решение проблемы, похожей на вашу.

Но все же лучше написать репозиторий, куда и вынести нужный вам функционал.

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде то, что нужно, но у меня DB first.

Answer (score 4):

Написать свой собственный метод, например, `entity.Get()`, который тоже будет выбирать все записи, но с учетом `IsDeleted`, и от него потом отталкиваться при дальнейших выборках - `entity.Get().Where(x => x ...)`.

Comment: Лучше написать репозиторий.

Comment: Обычно такие методы и выносятся в какой-нибудь репозиторий.